# Merge duplicated entries in array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, items

I am stuck with simple thing (at least I think it's simple),

I have an output from the database with duplicated entries and I would like to merge them. The output looks like this:

```
 ID   Name   Week   Active
 1    Steve  10     true
 2    Steve  11     false 
 3    Steve  12     true
 4    John   10     true
 5    John   11     false
 6    Emma   10     true
 7    Jane   11     true
```

So the array should look like this:

```
[
    [0] => [
        'id'     => 1,
        'name'   => 'Steve',
        'weeks' => [
             [0]  => [
                 'active' => true,
                 'week'   => 10
             ],
             [1]  => [
                 'active' => false,
                 'week'   => 11
             ],
             [2]  => [
                 'active' => true,
                 'week'   => 12
             ]
         ]  
    ],
    [1] => [
        'id'     => 2,
        'name'   => 'John',
        'weeks' => [
             [0]  => [
                 'active' => true,
                 'week'   => 10
             ],
             [1]  => [
                 'active' => false,
                 'week'   => 11
             ]
         ]  
    ],
    [2] => [
        'id'     => 3,
        'name'   => 'Emma',
        'weeks' => [
             [0]  => [
                 'active' => true,
                 'week'   => 10
             ]
         ]  
    ],
    [3] => [
        'id'     => 4,
        'name'   => 'Jane',
        'weeks' => [
             [0]  => [
                 'active' => false,
                 'week'   => 11
             ]
         ]  
    ]
]
```

Is it easy to accomplish?

Comment: You will have to loop through the results and add them to the array yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON as a workaround, where duplicated entries in the dictionary can be converted to an array, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416136/7471760